# Remove row from gridview with datatable datasource

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable, datasource

I am using VB.net.

I have a gridview with a datatable datasource.

What is the best option to update the datatable when i delete a row in the gridview and then show the gridview without that row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the row from the GridView should flag the row as deleted in the DataTable - which you can pick up on (iterating through the rows in the DataTable, you can examine the RowState of the DataRow and see whether the row has been deleted, and persist accordingly.